# FHIR IG Publisher templates

Tags: hl7-fhir

This `http://ots.nccn.org/documentation/site/StructureDefinition-order-template.xml.html`
 was generated on Apr 2017 and I have been some updates top the schema. I am new to this process and did some reading and saw this tool org.hl7.fhir.igpublisher that would create the new HTML for me. I download the JAR file and run the command but I am getting this error >Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: unknown version 1.9.0

```
java.exe -jar C:\Project\IGPublisher\org.hl7.fhir.igpublisher.jar -ig "C:\Project\IGPublisher\Publish\ig.json" -watch

FHIR Implementation Guide Publisher (v3.6.0-a77f48d9, gen-code v3.6.0 / 2) @ Wednesday, October 17, 2018 1:28:34 PM
Detected Java version: 1.8.0_191 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191 on amd64 (64bit). 1797MB available
[C:\Project\IGPublisher] -ig C:\Project\IGPublisher\Publish\ig.json -watch
Package Cache: C:\Users\mcdevitt\.fhir\packages
Load Configuration from C:\Project\IGPublisher\Publish\ig.json                   (00.0020sec)
Root directory: C:\Project\IGPublisher\Publish                                   (00.0106sec)
Terminology Cache is at C:\Project\IGPublisher\Publish\txCache. 243 files in cache (00.0147sec)
Contacting Build Server...                                                       (00.0148sec)
 ... done                                                                        (01.0177sec)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: unknown version 1.9.0
        at org.hl7.fhir.igtools.publisher.Publisher.getMasterSource(Publisher.java:1460)
        at org.hl7.fhir.igtools.publisher.Publisher.loadCorePackage(Publisher.java:1426)
        at org.hl7.fhir.igtools.publisher.Publisher.initializeFromJson(Publisher.java:1088)
        at org.hl7.fhir.igtools.publisher.Publisher.initialize(Publisher.java:946)
        at org.hl7.fhir.igtools.publisher.Publisher.execute(Publisher.java:525)
        at org.hl7.fhir.igtools.publisher.Publisher.main(Publisher.java:4927)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please take this up on https://chat.fhir.org/#narrow/stream/99-IG-creation (which you have)